# Laravel 5.7 variable being lowercased in HTML <option> tag

Tags: naming-conventions, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to make a ternary operation in my `option` tag. But when I call the variable, it becomes to lowercase and laravel could not find it.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="media_type" id="media_type" class="">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="image" {{ $campBanner->media_type == 'image' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Image</option>
    <option value="video" {{ $campBanner->media_type == 'video' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Video</option>
</select>
```

And here is the result of the laravel's exception:

```
<select name="media_type" id="media_type" class="">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="image" <?php echo e($campbanner->media_type == 'image' ? 'selected' : ''); ?>>Image</option>
    <option value="video" <?php echo e($campbanner->media_type == 'video' ? 'selected' : ''); ?>>Video</option>
</select>
```

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>
> Undefined variable: campbanner

Is it a bug? Or I just messed up something?

**UPDATE**

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\CampBanner;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCampBanner;

class CampBannerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
         return view('CampBanner.index', [
            'campBanner' => CampBanner::all()
         ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('CampBanner.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreCampBanner $request)
    {
        CampBanner::create(
            $request->validated()
        );

        return ['message' => 'Banner Camp baru telah ditambahkan'];
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\CampBanner  $campBanner
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(CampBanner $campBanner)
    {
         return view('CampBanner.show', compact('campBanner'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\CampBanner  $campBanner
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(CampBanner $campBanner)
    {
        return view('CampBanner.edit', compact('campBanner'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\CampBanner  $campBanner
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(StoreCampBanner $request, CampBanner $campBanner)
    {
        $campBanner->fill(
            $request->validated()
        )->save();

        return ['message' => 'Camp Banner berhasil diperbarui'];
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\CampBanner  $campBanner
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(CampBanner $campBanner)
    {
        $campBanner->delete();
        return ['message' => 'Camp Banner berhasil dihapus.'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your controller codes for better help ..

Comment: your controller codes seems good But on the create method you don't pass the variable.

Comment: Run these commands in your terminal :
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: use `@php
dd( $campBanner );
@endphp` on the first line of edit view. does it return anything?